# ein gutes Kilo vs. ein knappes Kilo

Tags: meaning, difference

Is "ein gutes Kilo" a little bit more than one kilo?
Is "ein knappes Kilo" a little bit less than one kilo or a lot less than one kilo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is "ein gutes Kilo" a little bit more than one kilo?

Yes.

> Is "ein knappes Kilo" a little bit less than one kilo or a lot less than one kilo?

No, it's just a little bit less.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: At least I use "ein gutes Kilo" if it is round about 1kg. It can also mean less.

Comment: Anstelle von "gutes" sagt man meistens eher "reichliches", wenn es etwas mehr ist. "Gutes" steht eher für "circa", d.h. +/- ein bisschen.